# No new login, but cached login work

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

Someone know if there is a problem to login the main site ?

I got that error from all browser;

[image]

All my cached login work. Chrome on my laptop, Safari on my iPhone, but I can't login no more if I clear my cache.

I even tested in Internet Explorer which got my credential saved and I get the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.

The root cause of this was a change to add more defense-in-depth to login.  We've been retiring bits and pieces of OpenID-ish login (which includes our email/password option, for historical reasons) for quite a while, and we moved more bits off of the public internet today - not all of our infrastructure got the memo (in particular parts involved in SO for Teams & Business*) so some logins were failing.

The change was rolled back, and we'll take another whack at it once we've figured out how to get everything on the same page.

<sub>*These parts are, for obvious reasons, very paranoid and defensive as they deal with private information.</sub>